# How to exchanged data between desktop and mobile applications based on managed code

Tags: .net, windows, activesync, mobile-devices

I develop the desktop application running under WinXPSP3 that should communicate to the other application, located at the mobile device running under Windows Mobile 2003/2005 and docked to the host with ActiveSync running. I have searched for some mechanism that looks like WCF, but failed to find any. Does BCL contain any classes that can help me, or I have to use 3rd party API?

Answer (score 0):

[WinToolZone](http://www.wintoolzone.com/ListDotNET.aspx) had an excellent CERapi tool which will allow you to communicate directly with the device via CERapi.dll... and it was compiled for the .NET 1.1 framework...I have had much success using that component which saved the day...

Look in there on that link for 'Components' and you will find CERapi in the dropdown box.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The CERapi is the nice tool, but it allows to get information about device, copy folders and files, but it doesn't contain tools to handle the cross-application communication channel.